# How to setup a TV set-top box using raspberry Pi?

Tags: television-tuner

I am not talking about Internet TV set top box (XBMC) using Raspberry Pi.I want to assemble one TV set top using Raspberry Pi. Is it possible? If it is then please tell what components are required?

For example we use Raspberry Pi GPIO to modify raspberry for a certain use, like as a PC, a tab, as a picture frame, as a motion detector, as a home automation system. Same as I want to use it as a TV set top box (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-top_box).

TV set top box

A set-top box (STB) or set-top unit (STU) is an information appliance device that generally contains a **TV-tuner input** (As somebody questioned me about using Television Tuner Tag) and displays output to a television set and an external source of signal, turning the source signal into content in a form that can then be displayed on the television screen or other display device.

Comment: I have no idea what the television-tuner tag means.  I do not understand what you want to do?  Could you clarify your question, perhaps by pointing to a product if that is what you want to make/copy?

Comment: I didn't find any tag related to television, So added which I found. I will try to give more details in question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You'll presumably need a USB TV tuner that works under linux as a first step.

I suggest that a good point to start your reading would be around MythTV (an open source digital video recorder), who say the Pi2 can do it:
https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi

I'm no MythTV expert, but I know it needs both a frontend and a backend to do what you want.  The backend is often run on a more powerful PC, but here's a blog post saying it can run on a Pi: http://planetgary.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/mythtv-backend-running-on-raspberry-pi.html

Do note though, that this will be a bit of a project to get working.